# VBA if cell equals certain value make that cell next available cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet called "JE", and in column C (C7:C446) users are able to populate the cells with account codes by two methods:

1. Double-clicking codes on a separate sheet called `acct_codes`
2. Manually enter the codes in column C. When the user manually enters the account code in column C, it is checked and changed to `#N/A` if it isn't listed in the `acct_codes` sheet to indicate to the user the code they entered was incorrect.

Column E is an account description column it will show the description associated with the account code in column C.

As it is now, the next available cell is the next blank cell in column C. 
I would like to make any cell in column E that equals `#N/A` to be the next available cell, THEN the next blank cell can be the next available cell.

---

**For example** if cell E11 has a value of `#N/A`, then the next time a user navigates to the `acct_codes` sheet and double-clicks a valid account code, I would like the account code they clicked to overwrite and populate C11.

---

I am unsure of the syntax to accomplish this and am having a hard time finding good example of this online. If anyone knows of a way I can go about doing this, I'd greatly appreciate it.

**Here is the code I have** in the `acct_codes` sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim acctDesc As Range
Set acctDesc = Range("E7:E446")

If Target.Column = 1 Then
    For j = 7 To 447
        If Worksheets("JE").Range("C" & j).Value = "" Then
             Worksheets("JE").Range("C" & j).Value = ActiveCell.Value
             Worksheets("JE").Activate
             Exit For
        End If
     Next j
End If

For Each Cell In acctDesc
    If Cell.Value = "#N/A" Then
        'Make that next available cell'
        'else make next blank cell next available'
    End If
Next Cell

Cancel = True  
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

```
Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim NextAvailableCell As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("JE")

        Set NextAvailableCell = .Range("C7:C447").Find(What:="#N/A", _
                                                       LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                                       LookIn:=xlValues)

        If NextAvailableCell Is Nothing Then
              Set NextAvailableCell = .Range("C7:C448").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
              .Cells(NextAvailableCell.Row, "C").Value = Target.Value
        End If
    End With

    NextAvailableCell.Value = Target.Value
        Cancel = True

    Call Back_to_JE 'calls a macro that brings user back to main form/sheet "JE"

End Sub
```

Comment: you can use `cell.offset` in for each loop to refer the next cell

Comment: Note: this is the single slowest thing you can do in VBA (activating, selecting, and reading (/writing) cell values inside a loop).

Comment: @Mat'sMug what is the slowest thing you can do in VBA, how my code is currently set up or the `cell.offset` option that was suggested?

Comment: Don't select & activate stuff. Don't work off the active cell. Don't read cell contents in a loop. Don't access worksheets in a loop.

Comment: I rolled back your post because it makes the question confusing for future readers and potential answerers if you remove the original content! Consider **adding** any additional details / code clearly labelled as an "edit" if you have problems with new code :)

Comment: @Wolfie will do. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

It would be much quicker to use `Find`

```
Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim NextAvailableCell As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("JE")
        ' Set equal to next "#N/A" cell
        Set NextAvailableCell = .Range("C7:C447").Find(What:="#N/A", _
                                                       LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                                       LookIn:=xlValues)
        ' If no "#N/A" cell was found then get last empty cell in column, 
        ' assuming it's above C448
        If NextAvailableCell Is Nothing Then
            Set NextAvailableCell = .Range("C448").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    End With
    ' Assign value of double clicked cell
    NextAvailableCell.Value = Target.Value
    ' Make it so that the double clicker doesn't enter the cell
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

This also avoids activating and selecting, which is good practise.

---

I'm unsure which cell you want to write to. If you want to search for `#N/A` in column `E` instead of column `C`, simply change that in the `.Range(___).Find` line. Ditto for the next blank cell in the relevant line.

If you want to *write* to a specific column, say column `E`, then use something like

```
' Inside the With block for ThisWorkbook.Sheets("JE")
.Cells(NextAvailableCell.Row, "E").Value = Target.Value
```

Comment: thanks so much. I would like to clarify something. Are you suggesting I replace this before double-click Sub with the entire sub I posted in my question? Or just incorporate the contents of this sub with the current sub I posted above. Thanks again

Comment: Yes you should be able to replace your entire sub, simple solution right?! I've added a note about which columns you're reading/writing to/from :)

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks so much. I appreciate your help

Comment: I replaced the sub you suggested with my previous sub. And it doesn't seem to be working. I placed it in the acct_codes sheet. When I double-click account codes (which are located in column A) in the acct_codes page, I'd like the account code being clicked on to populate the next available blank cell in column C or the cell in column C that has "N/A" inside of the corresponding E column cell. I have updated my code in the question. Do you know of any other modifications I could make?

Comment: So nothing to do with sheet "JE" as in your code? Where I have used a `With` block consider changing that line to reference the correct sheet....

Comment: When I double click an account code in the acct_codes sheet it populates the C column starting at C1. Currently I have an account code in cell C7 that isn't valid and this should replace that cell, not C1.

Comment: The code you've added to your question is different to my code... why have you changed the range just before the `End (xlUp)` command? Because that's likely why C1 is being selected. Also you're now assigning the value twice... do you understand my code or is there something I can clarify?